# Filling in the SelectList with a for loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Ok, my drop down used to be made like so:

```
<select id="Level" onchange="showChoice(this.value);">
     <option id="0" value="0">Pick a Level</option>
     @for (int i =1; i <= Model.ExamplesCount; i++ )
     {
         <option id="@i" value="@i">Level @i</option>
      }
</select>
```

because the ExamplesCount number changes per user.  But I need to use the `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` thing, which I can't get to work with this.

I need one of two solutions.

1. Can I make `Html.ValidationMessageFor()` work with this `select` tag?

or if not,

2.Can I use `Html.DropDownListFor()` but fill it in with a similar for loop?

For example,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Level, 
    new SelectList(
        new List<Object> {
             new {value = 0, text ="Pick a Level"},
             new { value = 1, text = "Level 1"},
             new { value = 2, text = "Level 2" },
             new { value = 3, text = "Level 3" },
             new { value = 4, text = "Level 4" },
             new { value = 5, text = "Level 5" } 
        },
     "value", "text", null))
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Level)
```

The above code works, but where I am hard coding all the SelectList values, I'd like to have an for loop that does it for me.

Comment: In the first example you would need to give the select a name attribute matching the property name so the MVC binder can match it up (e.g `<select name="Level" id=....>`) but I think this sort of logic is better done in the controller by building a `Selectist` based on you condition and then assigning it to ViewBag or a view model property then `@Html.DropDownListFor(m =>m.Level, ViewBag.MySelectList)`

Comment: I tried the name attribute thing and it didn't work. I'll try the SelectList and see how it goes.

Comment: Your view should only have code *specifically relating to the display*. Any data creation/selection work should be done in the controller and supplied either via your view model or via the `ViewBag`.

Comment: If you have a ViewBag entry named the same as your property (i.e. ViewBag.Level) containing your `SelectList` MVC will automatically use that if you just have `@Html.DropDownList("Level")`. It will combine it with a Model property to give you what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a object in your model that will content all the items you want an then pass that to your view? Example:

In your Model.

```
public class Model{
     ...other properties
    public List<ListItemSource> myLevels { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = @"*Required")]
    public string Level { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult YourAction(Model myModel)
    {
        var myModel = new Model
        {
            myLevels =methodToGetLevels()                
        };

        return view(myModel);
    }
```

In your View:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Level,
                         new SelectList(Model.myLevels, "Value", "Text"))

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Level)
```

Where x.Level will hold the selected value and Model.myLevels is the collection of levels.
I hope this help to solve your problem.

Comment: I ended up doing this but with SelectListItem instead of ListItemSource.  Thank you for your help.  This didn't really answer my original question, but since that was a bad question, this did solve my problem.

Comment: I'm glad this work for you. This is the awesome thing of stackoverflow everyone can helps :)