# MVC how do i populate dropdownlist without using a model

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am using mvc 4, i have a form in a view (not binded to a model), its using standard html elements.

I want to populate a dropdownlist from a list value (i.e return from controller action)

also based on the selection of a value from the first dropdownlist i want to populate a second dropdownlist

can someone please guide

Comment: When you say "from a list value" means you are sending back a list of values from your controller to your view and from that list you want to create a dropdownlist?

Comment: Why use MVC if you not even going to take advantage of its features (html helpers, model binding etc.). Create a view model to represent what you want to display! As for your second item, google _MVC cascading select_ or type it in he search box above and do some esearch

Comment: take a look to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24071618/filling-in-the-selectlist-with-a-for-loop/24072371#24072371  I agree with @Stephen Mueck you should use the awesome helpers that MVC give you.

Comment: I cant use a model because of poor design to a project. I need to submit a plain html form then rebuild the model in the controller

Comment: What do you mean you cant create a view model? `public class MyViewModel { public int SomeValueToBindTo { get; set; } public SelectList TheListOfOptions { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 0):

for the first dropdownlist you loop thru all the available options and add in `<option>` tags inside `<select>` for the second dropdownlist you need to either make bunch drop downs and hide/show them, or you create one big list and remove invalid entries base on the first list's selection. You would definitely need to do javascript for 2nd list.

Comment: i want to call an action method in controller that returns a list based on selection of first drop down list, hows that possible

Comment: @kayze then you return something like a json list and then use javascript to render it?

Comment: @kayze you need to make an Ajax call, I've explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a Model (you should though), you will have to add the items to `ViewData`
I'll stub something out for you and you can complete the rest.

Inside your controller, create a list object of what you need. If you are using EntityFrameWork this will look familiar.

```
var list = context.Table.ToList();   

List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> ddlItems = new List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>();

foreach (var item in list)
{
   ddlItems.Add(new SelectListItem(){ Text = item.Text, Value = item.Value.ToString()});
} 

ViewData["DDLItems"] = ddlItems;


@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LeagueId, 
 new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["DDLItems"], "Value", "Text")
 , "--Select League--", new { id = "league" })
```

You can define your second dropdownlist with just a placeholder until the cascade effect happens.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DivisionId, Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), 
                       "--Select Division--", new { id = "ddlDivision" })
```

Your going to need to use JQuery and fire and event when the dropdown changes, and then use Ajax to make a call back to the controller. Theres 2348239 examples online about making `Ajax` calls, know how to do that because it's done all the time in MVC.

I'll let you figure that part out. One hint, inside the Ajax call you can pass data to the controller. something like this `data: { leagueId: value }` where value is the value of the dropdownlist you want to cascade off of. `leagueId` **must** match type and name of the parameter your controller will expect.

Return a `Json` object from your controller like so...

```
public JsonResult GetDivisions(int leagueId)
{
    var division = //similar to before, fill a list.  

    return Json(divisions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And then in the success function of your Ajax call, you will populate the Second dropdownlist.

```
success: function (data) {                                                  

   $.each(data, function (index, item)    

 $('#ddlDivision')
            .append($('<option></option>')
            .val(item.Value)
            .html(item.Text))
```

`item.Value` and `item.Text` can be anything, just as long as the Json you return as the properties of `Text` and `Value`

IE...

```
 var divisions = (from x in context.Division
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Text = league + " " + x.Region,
                                     Value = x.DivisionId
                                 }).ToList();
```